# Select min value from Tables using (sub Select )

Tags: sql

I am trying to select a specific row from the tables. All are good, but the last select min is not working. So I need the min Leg Number after I make the whole selection.

```
SELECT cashier.* , legs.* ,cashier.id as cashier, 
cashier.cashierNumber as cashierNum ,cashier.fullName as cashier
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN  legs ON main.main= legs.legMain 
INNER JOIN  cashier ON legs.cashier = cashier.id 
WHERE legs.RRZZFrom ='RR' 
AND legs.LegNumber = (SELECT Min(legs.LegNumber) FROM legs)
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: try to run this statement SELECT Min(legs.LegNumber) FROM legs 
 independently and share the result.   If this will work and giving you results then your whole query also should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
  where legs.RRZZFrom ='RR' and legs.LegNumber in (select min(legs.LegNumber) from legs)
```

Comment: Hi @bilal, can you tell the value you are getting while running this query **SELECT Min(legs.LegNumber) FROM legs**

Comment: the value i need is the min leg number , in my case leg means row

Comment: if i put      WHERE legs.RRZZFrom ='RR' AND legs.LegNumber = 2    it will work , but i need it dynamic , Need the min value in this row after i make the whole selection

Comment: there is no condition written for **myTable**..is that correct?

Comment: `WHERE legs.RRZZFrom ='RR' AND legs.LegNumber = Min(legs.LegNumber)`..can you try this?

Comment: no, the conditions came in from the INNER JOINED tables

Comment: NOT WORKING    ///  WHERE legs.RRZZFrom ='RR' AND legs.LegNumber = Min(legs.LegNumber)

Comment: `SELECT Min(legs.LegNumber) FROM legs`..run this query and see the result..is it returning char or int?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try using cte.

```
with cte as (
  select min(LegNumber) as minLegNum from legs
)SELECT cashier.* , legs.* ,cashier.id as cashier, 
    cashier.cashierNumber as cashierNum ,cashier.fullName as cashier
    FROM myTable
    INNER JOIN  legs ON main.main= legs.legMain 
    INNER JOIN  cashier ON legs.cashier = cashier.id 
    INNER JOIN cte c on c.minLegNum = legs.LegNumber
    WHERE legs.RRZZFrom ='RR'
```

Comment: not what i want , i tried that before , i end up with same result

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the MIN leg number only from the selected data? In that case, something like this:

```
WITH Details
AS
(
    SELECT cashier.* , legs.* ,cashier.id as cashier, 
    cashier.cashierNumber as cashierNum ,cashier.fullName as cashier
    FROM myTable
    INNER JOIN  legs ON main.main= legs.legMain 
    INNER JOIN  cashier ON legs.cashier = cashier.id 
    WHERE legs.RRZZFrom ='RR' 
)
SELECT d.*
FROM Details AS d
WHERE d.LegNumber = (SELECT MIN(d2.LegNumber) FROM Details AS d2);
```

Not sure if you'd need to alias any other columns there, as I don't know the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT cashier.* 
          ,legs.* 
          ,cashier.id as cashier
          ,cashier.cashierNumber as cashierNum 
          ,cashier.fullName as cashier
          ,MIN(legs.LegNumber) OVER() AS [MinLegNUmber]
    FROM myTable
    INNER JOIN  legs 
        ON main.main= legs.legMain 
    INNER JOIN  cashier 
        ON legs.cashier = cashier.id 
    WHERE legs.RRZZFrom ='RR' 
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE LegNumber = [MinLegNUmber];
```

The idea is to use a `OVER()` clause to calculate the minimum value after the selection for each row:

```
MIN(legs.LegNumber) OVER()
```

Then in outer query to return only the rows which are matching this value.

The [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause is particular powerful syntax which allows to perform operations (ranking, aggregations) over given set of values. The `OVER()` syntax means the whole entity.

Comment: @bilal You mean to be executed in PHP or the logic to be performed in via PHP command?